# Shortest path that has crossings?

Tags: geometry

Consider a finite set of points in a surface of dimension 2. Is there any simple example, where the shortest closed path linking them all (like a possibly non-simple polygon, but with [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) instead of segments) crosses itself? It is impossible in a plane, I guess it is impossible when all [principal curvatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature) are positive (is my intuition correct?), what about saddle surfaces or something totally weird?

Context: I am just being curious.

Comment: "The shortest closed path linking them all" -- you mean like the travelling salesman problem? If so, the usual proof of non-intersection works anywhere the triangle inequality holds: you can locally uncross any intersection $\times$ into $||$ or $=$ and decrease the length.

Comment: @RahulNarain Exactly, I know that, I'm asking for a simple example where the triangle inequality does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As Rahul Narain already stated in a comment, you will never have self-intersecting paths as long as the triangle inequality holds.
Looking at the wikipedia article for [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), you [can find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Metric_space) that it holds for any metric space. This includes in particular the saddle surfaces you mention, and most other things one would commonly call a “surface”. And also most things where you can reasonably talk about a closest path linking a given set of points.

Wikipedia does mention Minkowski spaces as an example of a space where the triangle inequality does *not* hold. But as I'd consider the lengths of timelike vectors to be imaginary in such a space, I can't say I agree with this, as ordering complex numbers doesn't make that much sense.